# Unable to Update GridView in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to update and display a Value present in my **GridView**. What it does is that it obtains a value present in the label and switches to **TextBox** when I try to update it. Afterwards, I would like to display that particular value in a label outside of the **GridView**.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt = (DataTable)Session["anime"];

    dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Product_Quantity"] = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2")).Text;

    Session["anime"] = dt;
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        FillGrid();


    Response.Redirect("view_cart.aspx");
}



protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        if (drv != null)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("Label4")).Text);
            results.Text = sum.ToString();
        }
    }


}
```

Whenever I try to Update the row, it will return : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at **sum += Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("Label4")).Text);**

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: At: sum +=Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("Label4")).Text);

Comment: Are you sure the fourth cell of the row contains the Label. The index of the cells start at 0.

Comment: Yes, it is. The code runs without any problems, unless I choose to edit the row. From there, the exception will be thrown.

Comment: Debug your code to find out which item is null, my guess is Label4 as it is a readonly tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit the row, the EditTemplate is used. And in the there is no Label4. So the control cannot be found and the code will throw the exception. You then have to search for the TextBox2 control.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by doing the following:-

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {


    }

    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("Label4")).Text);
        results.Text = sum.ToString();

    }

}
```